# DB2 Stored Procedure: Declare an internal "rowset"

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I'm migrating some procedures from PostgreSQL to a new DB2 environment. I've got most of it done but I can't find a way to DECLARE a variable for an internal rowset/record.

Basically what the procedure does on Postgres is this:

```
DECLARE
    counts RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- fill "counts" with one row of aggregated data
    SELECT 
    COUNT(....) AS failed_inserts,
    COUNT(....) AS failed_updates,
    COUNT(....) AS failed_deletes,
    INTO counts
    FROM (...)

    -- check "counts" with some conditionals
    IF counts.failed_inserts > 0
        (...)
    END IF; 
    (...)

    -- return info depending on the data
    RETURN (...);

END
```

I can't find an equivalent to declaring "counts" in the IBM manuals or elsewhere online. The row I need is static (3 columns of aggregated data). So it would be enough to declare that row hardcoded if that is possible.

Is it possible to DECLARE a record / dataset / "virtual table" within a Stored Procedure on the DB2?

We're using DB2 for Linux (V10.5) not DB2 for iSeries.

**@mustaccio**'s answer points to the correct **solution**:

Outside of the procedure create the needed rowtype:
`CREATE TYPE empRow AS ROW (failed_inserts INTEGER, failed_updates INTEGER, failed_deletes INTEGER);`

Then you can DECLARE the new type within the procedure
`DECLARE newRow empRow;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you want, but may be you're looking for the `ROW` data type? Something like this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE counts_row AS ROW (
      failed_inserts INT,
      failed_updates INT,
      failed_deletes INT
    );
    counts counts_row;
BEGIN
    -- fill "counts" with one row of aggregated data
    SELECT 
    COUNT(....) AS failed_inserts,
    COUNT(....) AS failed_updates,
    COUNT(....) AS failed_deletes,
    INTO counts
    FROM (...);
    ...
```

PS. Not tested.

More info [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053377.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F4-3-4-1).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The DB2 didn't accept your code ('An unexpected token "<type declaration>" [...]') but with the help of the chapter of the manual that you pointed out I managed to complete the code. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Make sure you don't mix PL/SQL and DB2 SQL PL syntax in your code, and enable Oracle compatibility if you choose PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of creating a permanent** user defined type that is more or less specific to a single query, you can also achieve the same by using the [`FOR` statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004238.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-140):

```
FOR counts AS c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT COUNT(.....) AS failed_inserts,
                                   COUNT(....)  AS failed_updates,
                                   COUNT(....)  AS failed_deletes,
                              FROM (...)
DO
    IF counts.failed_inserts > 0 THEN
        (....)
    END IF;
END FOR;
```

** Permanent meaning something that's defined in the system catalog.